# Repeat every $ x $ coordinate except the last one

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation, filtering, vector

Below is the code to print the x value.

```
 ActCoorX = Range[0, 12000, 500]

   {0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, \
    4500, 5000, 5500, 6000, 6500, 7000, 7500, 8000, 8500, 9000, 9500, \
    10000, 10500, 11000, 11500, 12000}
```

Here I want to repeat every x coordinate. I tried with RepeatString and Subdivide, but then it repeats every x coordinate including last one which is not correct.

Also tried with Table,

```
Table[{x}, {x, 0, 12000, 1000}, {2}]
```

gives below which is again not not correct.

```
{{{0}, {0}}, {{1000}, {1000}}, {{2000}, {2000}}, {{3000}, {3000}}, \
{{4000}, {4000}}, {{5000}, {5000}}, {{6000}, {6000}}, {{7000}, \
{7000}}, {{8000}, {8000}}, {{9000}, {9000}}, {{10000}, {10000}}, \
{{11000}, {11000}}, {{12000}, {12000}}}
```

Are there any other ways to do repeat the coordinates? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to interleave a list with itself is `Riffle`. To remove the final value, use `Most`.

```
Most@Riffle[ActCoorX, ActCoorX]
```

**Updates:**

From your comment about `Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 12000, 595}]`, I think you don’t need to repeat coordinates. Maybe this is what you need:

```
Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, ActCoorX}]
```

If you don’t want `x` and `f[x]` for the last item, then:

```
Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, Most@ActCoorX}]
```

### Solution

From comments, the question is:

> How to make a table of `x` and `f[x]` for repeated values of a list, but not repeating the last value.

The most direct way might be:

```
Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, Most@Riffle[ActCoorX, ActCoorX]}]
```

However, to avoid recomputing `f[x]`, compute the table for `{x, f[x]}` one time, and then use `Riffle` and `Most`.

```
Most[Riffle[#,#]&@Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, ActCoorX}]]
```

The results are the same.

Comment: Can i use this Riffle with Table?

Comment: Lets say i have , Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 0, 12000, 595}]

Comment: yes , but then there is no repeatation of coordinates here.

Comment: Most@Riffle[ActCoorX, ActCoorX] this works perfectly.thank you!!

Comment: @user75507 - do you want `{x1, f[x1]}, {x1, f[x1]}, {x2, f[x2]}, {x2, f[x2]}`, ... until the end without repeating the last item? Or do you want to remove the last item like your Table example?

Comment: Yes.  {x1, f[x1]}, {x1, f[x1]}, {x2, f[x2]}, {x2, f[x2]}, ... until the end without repeating the last item, this was the aim.

Comment: using the third argument of `Riffle` (`Riffle[ActCoorX, ActCoorX, {1, -3, 2}]`) seems faster for large lists. (+1)

Comment: Could you please explain that what does exactly these {1, -3, 2} numbers represents here ?

Comment: @user75507 - `Riffle[list, x, {imin, imax, n}]` creates a new list in which *x* appears if possible at positions *imin*, *imin* + *n*, *imin* + 2 *n*, ... , *imax*. Try `va = Table[Subscript[a, i], {i, Range[5]}]; Riffle[va, x, {1, -3, 2}]`. `Riffle` inserts *x* starting at position 1 and stops 3 positions from the end (the negative number says: count from the end of the list). When `x` is a list, `Riffle` uses items from the second list in place of `x`. With two identical lists, the result is the same as using `Most@Riffle[list, list]`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want

```
ActCoorX = Range[0, 12000, 500];
Partition[ActCoorX, 2, 1]
```

> `{{0, 500}, {500, 1000}, {1000, 1500}, {1500, 2000}, {2000,  2500}, {2500, 3000}, {3000, 3500}, {3500, 4000}, {4000,  4500}, {4500, 5000}, {5000, 5500}, {5500, 6000}, {6000,  6500}, {6500, 7000}, {7000, 7500}, {7500, 8000}, {8000,  8500}, {8500, 9000}, {9000, 9500}, {9500, 10000}, {10000,  10500}, {10500, 11000}, {11000, 11500}, {11500, 12000}}`

Comment: thank you @cvgmt . Your syntax helps me to explore more about mathematica. Great!